# Why do all these commands on my ocm_cpuminer.exe black screen mean?

Tags: blockchain, mining

I have been using OnclickMiner to Mine for VertCoin, but still can't get exactly what's going on when I run the software. I have installed OneClick Miner and the wallet, to solo-mine. Now, I have enabled the CLI option in the OCM settings to show messages of what is actually going on, but still can't understand those messages.

What do these lines actually mean? I am attaching a screenshot of the OCM_CPUMiner.exe:

[image: OCM_CPUMinr.exe ScreenShot]

Now, if you have the expertise, please translate the lines of this black screen. Maybe it could be useful to others too. I have done a lot of search and nothing relevant showed up.

Incidentally, this is not a question about solo vs pool mining or a choice of which cryptocurrency to mine. Although that discussion would be very useful, I think I must ask in in another thread.

Comment: Are you trying to debug a problem, or do you have a specific question?

Comment: I am simply running ocm_cpuMiner and OneClick Miner to mine for VertCoin. I am only a simple user, and I am trying to understand what these messages mean. There are 9 different lines of message appearing on the console that I don't understand at all. I'd appreciate a lot if anyone could translate them into simple English for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be about programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Console Output and Meanings:

`Starting Stratum on stratum+tcp://localhost:9181` - The application is starting a stratum server hosted on your machine at port 9181.

`4 miner threads started, using 'lyra2rev2' algorithm` - You are mining on 4 different threads, probably each on a different core on your processor. The `lyra2rev2` algorithm is used to calculate the proof-of-work.

`Stratum difficulty set to 1 (.00391)` - The initial difficulty for mining is set, you will submit blocks that meet that difficulty.

`API bind to port 4084 failed` - The application is trying to start an API hosted on your machine on port 4084, but the port is probably unavailable or being used.

`CPU #x: xx kH/s` - This shows an updating hash rate per core that your machine is doing. E.g. `0.79 kH/s` is doing 790 hashes per second on that core.

`Stratum connection timeout` - The stratum sockets are full.
`Stratum connection interrupted` - The stratum connection was disconnected.

`lyra2rev2 block #, diff #` - This shows you the current block that has been mined on the network and the current network difficulty to mine the next block.

`accepted 1/1 (diff 0.009), 34.95kH/x yes!` - This is a share that was accepted from your miner by the pool you are mining on.

Comment: Thank you very much @JBaczuk but when I receive the message     `accepted 1/1 (diff 0.009), 34.95kH/x yes!` ---- and as you said, shows a share was accepted by my pool (in my case solo on my pc) doesn't it mean I must get paid for it? Is it a block that has been solved?

Comment: ... to put it more exactly, What I mean is what is the difference between `accepted 1/1 (diff 0.009), 34.95kH/x yes!` and `lyra2rev2 block 1056010, diff 131935.334` ?

Comment: The first one is a share, not a block, but eventually you should get paid, but usually you have to accumulate a minimum number of shares before you get paid.  The second line is just showing you that a block has been mined by someone else.